# How to send file from android to computer via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Anybody could give a working example of Bluetooth server client (from android to Computer)?

I want to transfer data from my Android mobile to C#  application. Right now I work with the below code for android which works good, but still it doesn't transfer data to my computer (may be can't write those data).

can anyone suggest some piece of code that should successfully transfer a message or a file from client Android to server PC?

```
Button btnSend = null;
TextView txtPath = null;
Socket s = null;
BluetoothAdapter objBluetoothAdapter = null;
BluetoothDevice device = null;
BluetoothSocket socket = null;
String strPath = "/sdcard/bluetooth/IMG0245A.jpg";
byte [] buffer = null;
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);
btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}
   @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String address="MY_COMPUTER_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS";

    objBluetoothAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(objBluetoothAdapter==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "BT not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return;
    }

    //objBluetoothAdapter.enable();

    if(!objBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBT);
    }
    try{
            device = objBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

            final UUID uuid= UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

            try{
                    File f = new File(strPath);
                    buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    bis.read(buffer,0,(int)f.length());

                    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                    Log.d("BT","RF Connection Created"+socket);
                    //objBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                            try{

                                    objBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                                    socket.connect();
                                    Log.d("BT","Socket Connected = "+socket);

                                    break;
                            }catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                    Log.d("BT","Socket Connection exception = "+e);
                            }
                    }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("BT","Connection NOT OK");
            }

            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(buffer);//,0,buffer.length);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            socket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,"exception "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

and this is some of my C# code. I use 32feet library

```
ObexListenerContext olContexet = obxlistener.GetContext();
ObexListenerRequest olRequest = olContexet.Request;
String[] pathSplits = olRequest.RawUrl.Split('/');
String filename = pathSplits[pathSplits.Length - 1];
olRequest.WriteFile(Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath) + "\\" + filename);
```

this code works good when I send a file from Bluetooth of android but when I try send a file from my android code, obxlistener.GetContext() returns null value!!!

thanks for helping

Comment: Can you put the code you are referring to in your question please?

Comment: I put my code. can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I stumbled on your question when reviewing an edit made by another user and saw that the code you mentioned was missing.